# Tomcat memory profilers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, jrubyonrails

Can someone suggest a good tomcat memory profiler? (I am trying to profile the memory usage of a JRuby on Rails app deployed on a Tomcat instance in a Windows machine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VisualVM which is part of the JDK - more recent versions can be downloaded from [visualvm.java.net/](http://visualvm.java.net/).

Or you can use the integrated profiler from NetBeans which is essentially the same thing as VisualVM just with some additional features.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/index.jsp). You can download trial version and see if it is good for you.

Last time I checked VisualVM does not show aggregated numbers. This means that you can see that, for example, your app has 10000 allocations of `int[]` array but you have no clue where these come from. YourKit has *Biggest objects (dominators)* screen which is quite helpful; you can see which objects take the most memory overall.